# Why am I only seeing part of the display while playing Whispered World?

Tags: the-whispered-world

My PC meets all the requirements for the game. However, I'm unable to see the full screen, only 2/3 of it. Viva's not too quick on giving me an answer.

Comment: What resolution are you running your monitor? Whispered World uses a resolution of 1024x768 which means a resolution lower than that will cause it to display incorrectly and one larger will cause it to be stretched.